# Copy all files from one drive to another filtering by date

Tags: windows, robocopy, xcopy

have been tasked with getting all files (not folders) from one drive with a date modified value of 19/01/2015 and copying them to the same location on another drive.

I have been looking in to xcopy but can't quite find the syntax to search all files and copy to the same location but on another drive.

It is on a Windows Server 2012 R2

Comment: Look at robocopy

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you try **RoboCopy** that comes with Win2012, and use "/minage:x" together with "/maxage:x". Example `robocopy [origin] [destination] /sec /minage:1 /maxage:2`.
It's not pretty but it should do the trick.

Check out http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx for the list of possible options.